# How to index list of user defined data type as a frozen on table "list<frozen<UDT>>"?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I have table contains column as foos `list<frozen <foo>>`,

Let foo is defined as foo

```
CREATE TYPE api.foo (
 arrival_date_time text,
    carrier_iata text,
    carrier_id text,
    carrier_name text,
    class_code text,
    departure_date_time text,
    flight_duration int,
    "from" text,
    "to" text,
    via text
);
```

How to index on table contains foos?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to index? what query do you want to be able to make?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I want to index arrival_date_time of each flight. I want to query like where list[0]['arrival_date_time'] > '12-06-2018 08:00'